# Yii2 cannot save model data in controller

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

I am trying to get value from title and I did but after pressing save button the title is not saving in database

```
$model = new Translation();
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    $getfromtitle = Yii::$app->request->post('Translation')['translation_title'];
    echo $getfromtitle;
    echo "<br />";
    $model->translation_drive_title = $getfromtitle;    
    echo $model->translation_drive_title;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "here";
    die();
}
```

after killing the code, yes everything is printing as I wanted but after pressing save/submit button (of course removing the die() function to let the code continue), the title which I got from first input is not saving to the second input $model->translation_drive_title in db

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving model before assigning value to `translation_drive_title`

```
$model = new Translation();
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $model->translation_drive_title = Yii::$app->request->post('Translation')['translation_title'];    
    $model->save();
}
```